# What is the proper way to set the route to a menu item from within a component?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, component, development

So I'm working on my a new component and I want to be able to route to a menu item when access is denied for a certain action.

I created a menu_id field in my table and I'm using the menuitem form field type to store the menu itemId.

I thought that I would be able to use the controllers setRedirect function like so

```
if($isRestricted && !$canDownload)
{
    $msg = $this->translate('COM_BABELU_PRODUCTS_DL_NOT_AUTHORISED');
    $this->setRedirect('index.php?itemId=101', $msg, 'warning');
    return false;
}
```

However it didn't work. it just appended the item id to the route

```
http://mysite.com/previous-menu-item-alias?itemId=101
```

This didn't even load the view associated with the menu item with the ID 101.

Do I need to specify the entire route? I.E. lookup the link from the #__menus table and then call JRoute with that value?

If anyone has exp with this I would really appreciate any information.

----Edit ---
I've done this before by querying the #__menus table directly and getting the link value then pushing that into JRoute. However I don't like the idea of querying the table directly because it creates a direct dependency. What I really want to know is how to get the link value without touching the #__menus table, or if there is a way to direct to a menu item using only the itemId.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/662/how-to-get-itemid-by-url-and-pass-it-to-jroute?

Comment: The question I'm asking is a little different. I don't need to find the itemId, because I have it stored in my database. Also I'm not trying to route to a view in my component, but any view that happens to be assigned to to the record. For instance com_content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. I found the answer.

First to get the item information without querying the `#__menus` table use this code:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$item = $menu->getItem($itemId);
```

Now the redirect is a little difficult, because I want to use the proper route, but if I just send the route to JRoute, I end up with an error because `JRoute` just appends the url content to the current active item. The below example is being called from the controller.

Example:

```
 //current url = http://mysite.com/product
 //$item->route = my-page 

$this->setRedirect(JRoute::_($item->route));
$this->redirect();


//resulting url = http://mysite.com/product/my-page
```

This of course throws a 404 because this route doesn't exist. "product" is part of my component "my-page" is a com_content article item.

However you can get around this by adding the URI:

```
$route = $item->route;
If((int)$item->home === 1)// its the home menu item, so clear the route
{
    $route = '';
}

$this->setRedirect(JURI::base().$route);
$this->redirect();

// resulting url = http://mysite.com/my-page
```

I also tested this with the `$item->link` vs the `$item->route` and it seems to work the same. It is probably better to use the link, just in case the site isn't using search engine friendly URLs.

I hope this helps!